# How to insert value in map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am having an issue with map.

```
map<int, map<int , int>> my_map;
```

I am using `insert()` like:

```
my_map.insert(10, my_map.second.insert(20, 30));
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The method to insert into map in dictionary is `add(key,value)`

Your code `my_map.insert(10, my_map.second.insert(20, 30));` will throw an error as `second' is not a method that can be called on map.

Here is what you can do to solve this issue:

```
map<int, map<int , int>> my_map;
map<int, int> my__second_map = new map<int,int>();

my_second_map.add(20,30);

my_map.add(10,my__second_map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an iterator of map type to call second. 
You could also use below code using map insert. You may also use pair data type.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::map<int, std::map<int , int> > my_map;
   std::map<int,int> data;
   data.insert(std::pair<int,int>(20,30));
   my_map.insert(std::pair<int,std::map<int,int> >(10, data));
   return 0;
}
```